# Optimizing Switch Statement / While Loop

Tags: javascript

My function takes in `f` which is another function of the following form:

```
// function f
mgf:function(p,n){
    return function(t){
        return Math.pow(1-p+p*Math.exp(t),n);
    };
}
```

with numbers `p` and `n`. It then generates a different function from this `f` function and variable values `h` and `x` based on `o` (the order, `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`) and runs a while loop until `v1` and `v2` are essentially equal, then finally returns this value:

```
derivative:function(f,o,x){
    var h=0.01,v1,v2;
    switch(o){
        case 1:
            while((typeof v1==='undefined' && typeof v2==='undefined') || Math.abs(v1-v2)>1E-5) {
                v1=(-f(x+2*h)+8*f(x+h)-8*f(x-h)+f(x-2*h))/(12*h);
                h-=h/2;
                v2=(-f(x+2*h)+8*f(x+h)-8*f(x-h)+f(x-2*h))/(12*h);
            }
            return v2;
        case 2:
            while((typeof v1==='undefined' && typeof v2==='undefined') || Math.abs(v1-v2)>1E-5) {
                v1=(-f(x+2*h)+16*f(x+h)-30*f(x)+16*f(x-h)-f(x-2*h))/(12*Math.pow(h,2));
                h-=h/2;
                v2=(-f(x+2*h)+16*f(x+h)-30*f(x)+16*f(x-h)-f(x-2*h))/(12*Math.pow(h,2));
            }
            return v2;
        case 3:
            while((typeof v1==='undefined' && typeof v2==='undefined') || Math.abs(v1-v2)>1E-5) {
                v1=(f(x+2*h)-2*f(x+h)+2*f(x-h)-f(x-2*h))/(2*Math.pow(h,3));
                h-=h/2;
                v2=(f(x+2*h)-2*f(x+h)+2*f(x-h)-f(x-2*h))/(2*Math.pow(h,3));
            }
            return v2;
        case 4:
            while((typeof v1==='undefined' && typeof v2==='undefined') || Math.abs(v1-v2)>1E-5) {
                v1=(f(x+2*h)-4*f(x+h)+6*f(x)-4*f(x-h)+f(x-2*h))/Math.pow(h,4);
                h-=h/2;
                v2=(f(x+2*h)-4*f(x+h)+6*f(x)-4*f(x-h)+f(x-2*h))/Math.pow(h,4);
            }
            return v2;
    }
}
```

As you can see this code is quite bulky and repetitive. Each case performs the exact same functionality but with a different function of the original `f` function. How can I optimize this code and rewrite it to be more readable? Can I extract the general algorithm:

```
while(x) {
    v1=y;
    h-=h/2;
    v2=y;
}
return v2;
```

and somehow have a parameter which is the function of `f`? Ie. `(-f(x+2*h)+8*f(x+h)-8*f(x-h)+f(x-2*h))/(12*h)`

Comment: You might want to post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. They might be able to give you better advice.

Comment: Can't you just take what is different and set those values as variables and use them in a common equation after the switch?

Comment: @epascarello, post that as the answer and I will accept. Sometimes it's nice to have a fresh set of eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per epascarello's comment, the solution is simple:

```
derivative:function(f,o,x){
    var h=0.01,v1,v2,f1;
    switch(o){
        case 1:
            f1=function(x,h){ return (-f(x+2*h)+8*f(x+h)-8*f(x-h)+f(x-2*h))/(12*h); };
            break;
        case 2:
            f1=function(x,h){ return (-f(x+2*h)+16*f(x+h)-30*f(x)+16*f(x-h)-f(x-2*h))/(12*Math.pow(h,2)); };
            break;
        case 3:
            f1=function(x,h){ return (f(x+2*h)-2*f(x+h)+2*f(x-h)-f(x-2*h))/(2*Math.pow(h,3)); };
            break;
        case 4:
            f1=function(x,h){ return (f(x+2*h)-4*f(x+h)+6*f(x)-4*f(x-h)+f(x-2*h))/Math.pow(h,4); };
            break;
    }
    while((typeof v1==='undefined' && typeof v2==='undefined') || Math.abs(v1-v2)>1E-5) {
        v1=f1(x,h);
        h-=h/2;
        v2=f1(x,h);
    }
    return v2;
}
```